Is there a way to get modelsummary() to work for negative binomial stan_glm estimates?
Since updating to version 2.0.0, modelsummary() continues to work with Poisson stan_glm(), but not with negative binomial stan_glm(). Does anyone have any suggestions for things that I could try please?
library(tinytable)
library(modelsummary)
library(rstanarm)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom.mixed)

# Poisson works
poisson <-
  stan_glm(
    cyl ~ mpg,
    data = mtcars,
    family = poisson(link = "log"),
    seed = 853
  )

modelsummary(poisson)
# tidy() output seems the same as the poisson
tidy(poisson)


# Negative binomial doesn't work
neg_binomial <-
  stan_glm(
    cyl ~ mpg,
    data = mtcars,
    family = neg_binomial_2(link = "log"),
    seed = 853
  )

# modelsummary doesn't built a table
modelsummary(neg_binomial)

# It seems like tidy() does return a `data.frame` with a column named "term".
tidy(neg_binomial)

The error message:
> modelsummary(neg_binomial)
Error: `modelsummary could not extract the required information from a model of class "stanreg". The package tried a sequence of 2 helper functions to extract estimates:
  
  parameters::parameters(model)
  broom::tidy(model)
  
  To draw a table, one of these commands must return a `data.frame` with a column named "term". The `modelsummary` website explains how to summarize unsupported models
  or add support for new models yourself: https://modelsummary.com/articles/modelsummary.html
  
  These errors messages were generated during extraction:
  
  `parameters::parameters(model)` did not return a valid data.frame.
`broom::tidy(model)` did not return a valid data.frame.

When I check the output of tidy(), it seems like it is the same as Poisson, which does work.

It may be that it is getting tripped up with the glance part? You can trick modelsummary a bit by doing something like this
library(tinytable)
library(modelsummary)
library(rstanarm)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom.mixed)



# Negative binomial doesn't work
neg_binomial <-
  stan_glm(
    cyl ~ mpg,
    data = mtcars,
    family = neg_binomial_2(link = "log"),
    seed = 853
  )



tidied_neg = tidy(neg_binomial)

glance_neg = glance(neg_binomial)

msummary_out = list(tidy = tidied_neg,
                    glance = glance_neg) 


class(msummary_out) = 'modelsummary_list'

modelsummary(msummary_out)


What a great idea. Thank you very much!
